# export bing map image using html2canvas. Only Pins show during export, base map doesn't load

Tags: vb.net, bing-maps, html2canvas

I have a .aspx page that finds the location of properties and places a pin at this location. I load the map in fine but when using html2canvas, My base map wont load. I am new to bing maps and this functionality and don't know what to do next. I don't know if i am supposed to load in a layer or tile source but here is my code for the following:

```
             <%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="comparableMapping.aspx.vb" Inherits="*.comparableMapping" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
<script charset="UTF-8" type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>
<script charset="UTF-8" type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var pinInfobox = null;
    var map = null;
    var currprop;
    var defaultInfobox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox();
    var layer1 = new Microsoft.Maps.EntityCollection();
    var MM = Microsoft.Maps;
    var PushPinsEntity = new Microsoft.Maps.EntityCollection();

    function GetMap() {
        map = new MM.Map(document.getElementById("mapDiv"),
                          {
                              credentials: "-",
                              width: 1100,
                              height: 650,
                              enablesearchlogo: false,
                              showScalebar: false,
                              zoom: 7
                          });
        map.entities.clear();
        <%=mapLocations()%>

    }

    function displayInfoBox(e) {
        var obj = e.target;
        var pinLoc = e.target.getLocation();
        var pinId = e.target.getText() - 1;
        var pinId = e.target.pinId - 1;
        currprop = props[pinId].split("~");

        var name = currprop[0];
        if (name !== null) {
            var info = name + "<br/>";
            info += currprop[5] + "<br/>";
            info += currprop[6] + ", " + currprop[7] + " " + currprop[8] + "";
        } else {
            var info = currprop[5] + "<br/>";
            info += currprop[6] + ", " + currprop[7] + " " + currprop[8] + "";
        }
        //closeInfoWindow();
        //map.entities.remove(defaultInfobox);

        //var infoboxOptions = { title: currprop[1], width: 250, height: 140, description: info, offset: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(-1, 45) };
        var infoboxOptions = { title: currprop[1], description: info };
        defaultInfobox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(map.getCenter(), infoboxOptions);
        defaultInfobox.setLocation(pinLoc);
        map.entities.push(defaultInfobox);
        //Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(defaultInfobox, 'mouseleave', function () { defaultInfobox.setOptions({ visible: false }); });
    }

    function closeInfoWindow() {
        el = document.getElementById('InfoWindow');
        el.style.display = 'none';
    }

    function zoomInToProperty(e) {
        var loc = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(currprop[3], currprop[4]);
        map.setView({ center: loc, zoom: 20 });
    }

    function zoomOutOfProperty(e) {
        var viewRect = Microsoft.Maps.LocationRect.fromLocations(locs);
        if (locs.length > 1) { map.setView({ bounds: viewRect }) } else { map.setView({ center: locs[0], zoom: 6 }) };
    }

    function captureScreen() {
        html2canvas($("#mapDiv"), {
            logging: true,
            useCORS: true,
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                //document.body.appendChild(canvas);
                var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                window.open(img);
                //var a = document.createElement('a');
                //a.download = name;
                //a.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                //document.body.appendChild(a);
                //a.click();
            },
        });

    }
 </script>
 </asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<div style="margin-top:10px;">
    <div id='mapDiv' class="map">
    <script type=”text/javascript”>GetMap();</script></div><br />
    <input id="load" value="save" type="button" onclick="captureScreen();"/>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:left;"></div>
</asp:Content>
```

[image: the left hand picture is map map with loaded locations. the right is my image i am exporting without the base map loaded in]

Comment: Something tells me that html2canvas did not go through all the internal div. You might have to trick it to loop through each internal div manually and render it on your canvas in the right order.

Answer (score 2):

Just need to enable:`enableCORS: true` in the maps option, too need config `userCORS: true,` in options in the html2canvas scripts